# What is the measurement for oxygen?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm writing a motivational piece of text and I'd like to write the following:

> The human body will work until the last ***_*____** of oxygen is depleted.

I'm not sure what would be the proper measure for oxygen. I don't want *drop of oxygen*, because I'm using that later for *drop of blood*.

Comment: This question can be improved by adding the references you checked before asking, what you found, and why the results were inadequate. Please check the [faq] for more on basic site etiquette.

Comment: It's difficult to google for an answer like this, when you're supposed to be googling a word you don't know, right?

Comment: http://thesaurus.com/browse/small+amount

Comment: http://onelook.com/ provides reverse lookup on any phrase.

Comment: Are you asking in a medical, sports, metaphoric or other context?

Comment: Sports/poetic/metaphoric should work.

Comment: For creative suggestions, you should try writersSE. Voting to close as not a real question: likely to lead to a debate.

Comment: Oxygen is a gas, so it is measured in litres.

Comment: @MattЭллен True, although it's often purchased by weight (e.g. [pounds or ounces](http://www.bernzomatic.com/products/fuel.aspx) if you're in the US, though it may come in liquid form).

Comment: In geek speak: molecule, atom, mole. In poetic speech: vestige, trace, wisp. In clueless speech: gallon, piece, school.

Comment: No matter what word you opt for, the sentence won't work because *deplete* is the wrong verb stylistically. You can't deplete a measurement. You can only deplete a container.

Answer (score 6):

I would consider "the last *ounce* of oxygen". It has a pleasant alliteration and among its [definitions](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ounce) is "a small amount". Although it may not lend itself well to literal interpretation, it sounds like that's not the intent here.

Comment: Or "milliliter of oxygen" if you're not an American, I suppose.

Comment: @Jay Then you lose the mellifluousness! Although I like the consonance in "milliliter" on its own.

Answer (score 4):

I'll put my money on "molecule".

But I don't know if this statement would actually be true... ;)

Comment: It wouldn't be. But that doesn't make it _sound_ any less cool.

Comment: Any more than it would be true to say "last drop of blood". Both are, perhaps, a poetic exaggeration, depending on the context.

Answer (score 4):

How about:

> The human body will work until the last *breath* of oxygen is depleted.

I like that wording partly because that's how oxygen is brought into the body, generally  speaking.  Moreover, the word *breath* is sometimes used figuratively as well (as in *breath of fresh air*, or *breath of a scandal*, e.g.), so you needn't be overly concerned about using the word to mean *a small, indeterminate amount*, because there's precedent for that.

So, you wouldn't necessarily be referring to a literal last breath of oxygen – but you're not referring to a literal last drop of blood, either, so I assume that wouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

The statement is not factually correct unless the measure is 'the minimum amount needed to function'. So something like gasp would be best:

> "... will work until the last gasp of oxygen ...".

Answer (score 2):

If you mean that breathing has stopped and it's using up oxygen in the system then you would normally say "the last *reserves* of oxygen"

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use `work`, but `function` for this kind of sentence; I also would work around the issue with a more generic:

> The human body will continue to function as long as there is enough oxygen available.

Answer (score 0):

Blood oxygen is measured as a percentage of saturation. [This is a good explanation.](http://www.health.harvard.edu/diagnostic-tests/oxygen-saturation-test.htm)

So if you don't mind sounding overly technical, I suppose you could say:

> *The human body will work until the last percentage of oxygen is depleted.*
>
> *The human body will work until its blood oxygen saturation drops to 0%.*
>
> *The human body will work until its blood oxygen level drops to 0%.*

Or you could say,"The human body will work until the last atom of oxygen is depleted."

(The body might actually quit working at a much higher percentage than 0%, but I'll leave that to you to ferret out.)

Comment: The OP did ask about the "proper measure for oxygen."

Comment: This is good if the writer wants to make a technical statement, like "body will function until the blood oxygen levels falls below 6%" (or whatever the number is -- I just made that number up). But I think from the phrasing of the question he's looking for a less-technical wording. "This diet forces me to count every calorie I eat" has a rather different tone then "This diet requires me to measure the food I eat with an accuracy of at least plus or minus two ounces."

Comment: “...until the last atom of oxygen...” works as hyperbole, but molecule is more accurate, as it is O_2 that binds to [hemoglobin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hemoglobin#Iron.27s_oxidation_state_in_oxyhemoglobin), rather than O.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with 'whiff of oxygen'

Answer (score 0):

Gasses are [measured by volume](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_metre) (at STP), using the SI unit of **cubic meters**. The concentration of oxygen that's part of the air we breathe, a mixture containing other gasses, is measured in *[parts-per](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parts-per_notation)-X*.

E.g., Earth's atmosphere contains [209,460](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmosphere_of_Earth) *parts-per-million* of oxygen by volume, or roughly 20%.

Of note for respiration, the [partial pressure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_pressure) of oxygen is more important than its PPM ([ehstoday.com](http://ehstoday.com/safety/confined-spaces/ehs_imp_32784): *Confined Spaces*).

---

I'd use, "...until the last *drop of oxygenated blood* reaches the brain" and *"that same drop of blood..."* for the other sentence. Blood does a lot of stuff.

Also note: the human body will stop working *way*<sup>1</sup> before its last **vestiges** of oxygen are depleted.

<sub>1: to be read with echo, reverb and chorus.</sub>